# Which is more correct: “skewen” or “skewn”?

Tags: etymology, history, past-participles, conjugation, middle-english

Which spelling for the past participle of *skew* is more correct: *skewen* or *skewn*?

(I recognise it is not the more common spelling of *skewed*, but regionally and personally *skewen* is more in use in Quebec.)

Also, out of curiosity, is *skewn* even a word? Or was it ever a word?

I’m thinking of *strew/strewn* and *sew/sewn* and am wondering whether *skew* ever matched to *skewn* at any point over the course of its usage.

Comment: -1 If "is skewn even a word?" then how do you ask "Which spelling ... is **more correct** ?"

Answer (score 4):

OED doesn't mention *skewen* or *skewn,* which means that the use is extremely local. Every dictionary has a lower limit below which they don't list a word; OED's is very low indeed. However, the entry dates from 1911 and an update is awaited.

Their earliest citation for *skew* in the sense "crooked, oblique" is

> **2.a.** To take an oblique course or direction; to turn aside, move sideways.
>
> 1488  (1478)    Hary *Actis & Deidis Schir William Wallace* (Adv.) (1968–9) ix. l. 272   Crawfurd drew saill, skewyt by and off thaim past.

It's a Middle English word, and the entry indicates that shortly after the verb entered English from Old Northern French, the past participle was [what is now] *-ed* rather than *-n*.

> < Old Northern French *eskiu(w)er, eskuer, escuer,* variant of Old French *eschuer, eschever, etc.:* see **eschew** *v.*<sup>1</sup> The later development of sense is curious, as well as the apparent use of the verb-stem in the adverb **askew** *adv.* and the adjective **skew** *n.*<sup>1</sup>

There is a slightly earlier citation from *Morte Authure* which uses *skew* in the now-obsolete sense of *escape*, but the snippet doesn't include the past participle to see how it was formed in that source.

*Sew, strew* and *throw* are Old English and follow the Germanic form of *-en* for the past participle.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the use on 'skewen' as past participle  of *to skew* is local/ regional since it is a regular verb. Probably from its Middle English  origin.

[To skew](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/skew): ( regular verb) skewed, skewed.

> - is to turn or place at an angle. When you build a house of cards, you must slightly angle, or skew each card, so structure will stand up.
>     **From the Middle English skewen** ("swerve"), this verb was born to describe things in the physical world. Nowadays, though, we encounter it more informally: If you're in advertising, you might skew (target, aim) your commercials toward a particular demographic. Even before that, you may collect some statistical data on your intended audience, and then make sure that data is accurate, because bad or irrelevant info might skew (distort, inaccurately depict) the results of your research.

Source:http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/skew

Origin of skew:

> - 1350–1400;  (v.) **Middle English skewen**  to slip away, swerve < Middle Dutch schuwen  to get out of the way, shun, derivative of schu  ( Dutch schuw ) shy1 ; (adj.) derivative of the v. (probably influenced by askew); (noun) derivative of the v. and adj.

Source:http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/skew

I could not find any evidence on 'skewn'.